# Can't Cast Type (Public Activity Instance) to Activity in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to access a public class from my activity. I have a public class called `HomePageActivity` (It's using `AppCompatActivity`) which is that public class activity contains another class called `Model.User CurrentUser` (It's for calling current user since login by calling the userEmail on my database model property). HomePageActivity contains shared preference and I store all of the user data with variables such as current user, userID and email and I can call it from another class. In the next activity (UploadActivity), I want to access `HomePageActivity` and its attributes.

**So, what I do :**

1. Declare the `HomePageActivity` in my next activity which is in `UploadActivity` ==>  `public HomePageActivity m_currentActivity;`
2. Call the `m_currentActivity` inside `onCreate` since I use `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` ==> `m_currentActivity = (HomePageActivity) this.Activity;`
3. Try to call the `m_currentActivity` on my needed area ==> `m_currentActivity.idUser;`

But, I failed. I stuck. I can't cast HomePageActivity. Fortunately, I can use `m_currentActivity = (HomePageActivity) this.Activity;` on my `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` (on another fragment) but, why in `UploadActivity` which uses `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` I can't cast my `HomePageActivity`

**What happens if I don't use `m_currentActivity = (HomePageActivity) this.Activity;` ?**
Well, based on my previous trial and error on my fragment and also on my UploadActivity, if I don't declare and cast the HomepageActivity, I can't get the value of the entities such as I can't get the value of `m_currentActivity.idUser`. If I debug, it will return null or crash like

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I've searched a lot of articles, but I still can't get my answer. I hope to hear the answer and recommendation from all of you. Thank in advance!

Comment: I could access the property of one activity in second activity when i set the property with public. Could you show us the code to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guys thank you for your response. Basically, I use intent and I access from my main class. Before it, I already put global variables in my main activity so, I can call them and access them from the main activity

Answer (score 0):

this.Activity is only available inside of the Fragments. If your `UploadActivity` inherits from  `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` you will not get this.Activity. If you are running any fragments inside the `UploadActivity` than inside those fragments you will get this.Activity of type `UploadActivity`.
If  you some data to take with you to next activity use Intents. If you really want complete context of the last activity use a `static` property in the first activity and pass `this` in it. In you case create a static property in `HomePageActivity` and of type `HomePageActivity` and in `OnCreate` method pass `this`(current instance) in it. This property will be available through out the project. Make sure to use it if you absolutely have to.